# Can I use multiple grids to occupy the same space?

Tags: c#, wpf

I’m new to WPF, and I’m planning a desktop app that will have multiple screens for each function it provides. Each “screen” will occupy the same space, just not at the same time. I could use a tab control, but want to try for a different look.  I was thinking I could create multiple grids, and just move them in and out via changing the margins property with animation.

Is this possible? Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use some sort of parent panel and then place each grid at the root of the parent panel.  Then, showing / hiding each is a simple matter of setting visibility.  The grids, set to stretch, will take up the entire screen assuming the panel doesn't have any padding / margins.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that was ok.